# Is circular dependency acceptable?

Tags: typescript, rest, nestjs, prisma

I have a users table and a posts table. 
The user can't exist without at least one post. 
I have next "UsersService":

```js
class CreateUserDto {
  firtname: string;
  lastname: string;
  postIdToAssign: number;
}

class UsersService {
  constructor(
    private readonly postsService: PostsService,
    private readonly prisma: PrismaService,
  ) {}
  
  createUser(dto: CreateUserDto) {
    if (this.postsService.find(postsIdToAssign) {
      throw new PostAlreadyAssignedError();
    }   
    
    return this.prisma.user.create({
      data: dto,
    })
  }
}
```

For checking post existence, should I use "postsService.find" method (in code above), or do directly

```
if (this.prisma.post.findFirst({where: {id: postIdToAssign}}) // then throw Error
```

Main concern here is should I use method from PostsService or no, because if use PostsService method - in some case "PostsService" can get need to use some of "UsersService" methods and we'll got circular dependency. Or this is normal scenario?

Answer (score 0):

There are actually two concerns.

1. Circular dependency in code leads to compilation problems in typescript.
2. Circular dependency in the architecture/logic usually leads to a mess.

There is simple way to fix both. We just mechanically break the circular dependency in compilation. For that to be logical we need to determine primary/secondary relationship. For example in case of users and posts I would set users as primary and posts as secondary. For those things of users we need in posts we define interface and put it to separate file (or even to posts file if nobody else needs it). The reference to posts functionality in users file remains untouched. And to reference users functionality in posts we now have the interface. The circular dependency problem is fixed.

What is interesting is that applying such simingly mechanical and verbose approach systematically we get onion structure of code. I don't tell that it is the same thing described in varios architecture books, but I enjoy the method very much as it is very straightforward and doesn't require any philosophy.